# Distribution of users onto sessions according to specific rule

Tags: python, otree

for a simple app I try to develop a function that distributes player to different sessions (or treatments). For that purpose, I use a in built "creating_session" function.

At first, every session 1 to 3 should contain in this example 4 participants. Therefore, from the 12 first participants, 4 should be in session 1, session 2 and session 3.

The next participants should be randomly distributed onto the treatments.

The code below is working. However, in the real application I will have more than ten treatments.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way that I can make the code easier or shorter.

```
    def creating_session(subsession):
        import random
        c1 = 0
        c2 = 0
        c3 = 0
    
        for player in subsession.get_players():
            for i in range(50):
                treatment_rest = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
    
                if treatment_rest == 1:
                    c1 = c1 + 1
                    if c1 <= 4:
                        treatment = 1
                        break
                    elif c2 <= 4 or c3 <= 4:
                        continue
                    else:
                        treatment = 1
    
    
                elif treatment_rest == 2:
                    c2 = c2 + 1
                    if c2 <= 4:
                        treatment = 2
                        break
                    elif c1 <= 4 or c3 <= 4:
                        continue
                    else:
                        treatment = 2
    
    
                elif treatment_rest == 3:
                    c3 = c3 + 1
                    if c3 <= 4:
                        treatment = 3
                        break
                    elif c1 <= 4 or c2 <= 4:
                        continue
                    else:
                        treatment = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly many ways to achieve this. One of them is the following:

```
def creating_session(subsession):
    import random
    treatments = [1, 2, 3] * 4
    random.shuffle(treatments)

    for player in subsession.get_players():
        player.treatment = treatments.pop() if treatments else random.randint(1, 3)
```

Let me explain what's going on here:

- First of all, a list of all treatments is created and multiplied by 4 to have each treatment exactly 4 times in the list: `treatments = [1, 2, 3] * 4`.
- Then the list is shuffled to randomize the distribution of these treatments among the first 12 participants: `random.shuffle(treatments)`.
- And finally, in the player loop, it is checked whether there are any treatments left in the list. If so, a treatment is removed from the list and assigned to the player. If not, i.e. the 12 treatments from the list have been used up, a random treatment integer between 1 and 3 (both included) is assigned to the player: `player.treatment = treatments.pop() if treatments else random.randint(1, 3)`.
  The last line of code uses python's ternary operator and is a shortcut for:

  ```
    if treatments:
        player.treatment = treatments.pop()
    else:
        player.treatment = random.randint(1, 3)
  ```

  This is not as short, but perhaps easier to read and understand.

Note: The above code assumes that a field named "treatment" has been defined in the player model:

```
class Player(BasePlayer):

    treatment = models.IntegerField()
```